# Error building ios platform in Cordova 6.4.0

Tags: ios, cordova

Cordova create and add platform works fine but get error message while building in ios. i have Xcode 7.3.1 and cordova 6.4.0 mac version is 10.11

```
Error: xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```